# Application insights sink option not showing Performance counter in the Application insights for service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

Below is the configuration I have setup for Application Insights sink to send EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration and EtwManifestProviderConfiguration and PerformanceCounters.

```
                "WadCfg": {
                  "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                    "overallQuotaInMB": "50000",
                    "sinks": "applicationInsights",
                    "EtwProviders": {
                      "EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration": [
                        {
                          "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors",
                          "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "1",
                          "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                          "DefaultEvents": {
                            "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableActorEventTable"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services",
                          "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                          "DefaultEvents": {
                            "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "EtwManifestProviderConfiguration": [
                        {
                          "provider": "cbd93bc2-xxxx-4566-b3a7-xxxxxxxx",
                          "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Information",
                          "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "4611686018427387904",
                          "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                          "DefaultEvents": {
                            "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricSystemEventTable"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "PerformanceCounters": {
                      "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                      "PerformanceCounterConfiguration": [
                        {
                          "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time",
                          "sampleRate": "PT1M",
                          "unit": "Percent",
                          "sinks": "applicationInsights"
                        },
                        {
                          "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(My.WebAPI)\\Private Bytes",
                          "sampleRate": "PT1M",
                          "sinks": "applicationInsights"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "SinksConfig": {
                    "Sink": [
                      {
                        "name": "applicationInsights",
                        "ApplicationInsights": "d504ba9a-xxx-42b7-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "MyApplicationInsightsProfilerSink",
                        "ApplicationInsightsProfiler": "d504ba9a-xxxx-42b7-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "StorageAccount": "sfdgjsxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              }
            }
          },
```

I do not see any of the events or performance counter in Log.

[image: Application Insights Log]

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: no still have the issue

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you like, you can email me at AzCommunity@microsoft.com and provide me with your SubscriptionID and link to this issue. I can enable your subscription for a free support request to have this investigated further.